# How to return a name alongside certain values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Let's say I have a sheet of student data.

- column A: grade level
- column B: student name
- [not relevant: columns C - G: absences, parents' phone number, credits completed, etc]
- column H: GPA

I want to find the highest GPA in each grade level and return the GPA and the name of the student associated with that GPA. How would I do that in Google Sheets?

I know how to return the highest GPA by grade level using a query but I don't know how to return a value from another column (name) along with it.

Comment: The below thread should help [Return Max Value with Vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998004/return-max-value-with-vlookup-from-list)

Answer (score 1):

To get Max_GPA against a GradeLevel, I used formula from post which i have commented in this thread.

To get the name corresponding to Max_GPA, I am using a VLOOKUP. Points to note while using Vloopup: 
1) Ensure the left most column should contain values which we are looking for (in the screenshot - E2). Thus GPA has to be the first column.

[image]

Since VLOOKUP comes with a limitation of placing GPA values in the first column, the better approach is to use a INDEX and MATCH function together. 
[image: Image2]
Source : http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/